# How to bind WPF image when using "Binding" element

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I have the following XAML:

```
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="9" Margin="5">
                <Image.Source>
                    <Binding Path="{Binding ImgProp, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="..\..\PlaceholderImage.png" />
                        </Binding.TargetNullValue>
                    </Binding>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
```

However that fails with the error `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`.

Changing it to:

```
                    <Binding Path="ImgProp">
```

Fails with `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject`.

The ViewModel is properly wired and implements interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property `ImgProp` is setup in WPF MVVM fashion.

Obviously binding in this way is different than normally going `<Image Source={Binding ImpProp}/>`, but I can't seem to find any information on the internet or stackoverflow how to fix it or how it's proper to do it.

How do I bind an image source to a viewmodel property when the `<Binding>` element is seperatedly used like in my code?

Comment: `<Binding Path="ImgProp">` is the correct syntax. You must however make sure that the  ImageSource that is the value of the `ImgProp` property is accessible in the UI thread by calling its `Freeze()` method.

Comment: @Clemens, but in my case I am not updating the image in code, there is no code apart from the XAML, how do I do it then?

Comment: "*there is no code apart from the XAML*" can not be true. There is a view model object (in the DataContext) that has an ImgProp property that is assigned somewhere.

Comment: @Clemens, so I should freeze the `BitmapImage ImgProp { get { ... } set { ... } }` property in the viewmodel?

Comment: Yes of course, before you assign it to the property.

Comment: @Clemens, since the viewmodel code is just `public ViewModel(Book book) { ImpProp = book.Img; }` I should add `ImpProp.Freeze();` at the end? Just like that?

Comment: FYI you can bind a `string` or `byte[]` to the `Image.Source` property. So you can bind the filename of the image or the raw bytes of the image and you can get rid of an UI-Type inside your ViewModel

Comment: Very true, neither the view model nor the model (Book) should declare a property of type BitmapImage, or one of its base classes like ImageSource. They should instead declare a string property that holds an URI string, which may identify a file in the local file system, an assembly resource file, or even a web resource.

Comment: @SirRufo, I can bind `byte[]` to the image source?!?! I was toiling away at a method that converts `byte[]` to `BitmapImage` exactly because I thought it can't! xD I'll change it to that but this question still holds.

Comment: @Clemens, although I will change it, I still have never encountered such a problem and am now wondering why it seems like an entirely alien thread is creating the Image controls on my UI usercontrol, as even with using the dispatcher I get an error message saying I can't modify the property from a different thread.